OAK-D PRO rgbd_odometry: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! (ROS-noetic)
I ran rtabmap.launch with the DEPTHAI-ROS driver, but the following error appears:
[ WARN] [1719562216.917623799]: /rgbd_odometry: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set.
/rgbd_odometry subscribed to (approx sync, max interval=0.020000s):
/oak/rgb/image_raw 
/oak/stereo/image_raw 
/oak/rgb/camera_info
here is my launch file
<!-- camera -->
<include file="$(find depthai_ros_driver)/launch/camera.launch">
    <arg name="name" value="$(arg name)"/>
    <arg name="params_file" value="$(arg params_file)"/>
</include>



<!-- rtabmap_odom -->
<node type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" pkg="rtabmap_odom" output="screen">
    <remap from="rgb/image" to="$(arg name)/rgb/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg name)/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="depth/image" to="$(arg name)/stereo/image_raw"/>
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="$(arg name)"/>

    <rosparam param="subscribe_depth">True</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="approx_sync">True</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="approx_sync_max_interval">0.02</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="sync_queue_size">100</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="sub_queue_size">100</rosparam>
    
</node>

<!-- rtabmap_slam -->
<node type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_slam" output="screen">
    <remap from="rgb/image" to="$(arg name)/rgb/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg name)/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="depth/image" to="$(arg name)/stereo/image_raw"/>
    <rosparam param="Rtabmap/DetectionRate">3.5</rosparam>
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="$(arg name)"/>
    
    <rosparam param="subscribe_depth">True</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="approx_sync">True</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="approx_sync_max_interval">0.02</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="sync_queue_size">100</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="sub_queue_size">100</rosparam>

</node>

<!-- rtabmap_viz -->
<node type="rtabmap_viz" name="rtabmap_viz" pkg="rtabmap_viz" > 
    <remap from="rgb/image" to="$(arg name)/rgb/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg name)/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="depth/image" to="$(arg name)/stereo/image_raw"/>
    
    <rosparam param="subscribe_depth">True</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="approx_sync">True</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="approx_sync_max_interval">0.02</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="sync_queue_size">100</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="sub_queue_size">100</rosparam>
</node>

can you help me pls?
thank you for reading
